# Switch positions of StateImage and IndexImage for a TreeNode in a Winforms TreeView control

Tags: vb.net, winforms, .net-3.5, treeview, treenode

I would like to know if it is possible to switch the position of a StateImage with that of an IndexImage for a TreeNode in a Winforms TreeView?

Please refer to the image below for an illustration.

[image: A TreeNode with a StateImage and the bottom TreeNode without a StateImage]

The first TreeNode has a stateImage and the second one doesn't.

My aim is for all IndexImages to align to the left and the StateImage (if any) to be to the right of the IndexImage.

The resulting tree would look something like:

[image: resulting tree with IndexImages aligned left]

I think i have to set the tree DrawMode to OwnerDraw and override OnPaint. I read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.drawnode.aspx) msdn link but nothing there was said about drawing images. I really don't know how to proceed. Any help and code you could provide (in C# or VB.net) will be very much appreciated.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this would require custom drawing.

```
TreeView1.DrawMode = TreeViewDrawMode.OwnerDrawAll
```

Then you have to handle the DrawNode event.  See [TreeView.DrawNode Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.drawnode%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

The `DrawTreeNodeEventArgs` parameter in the `DrawNode` event has a graphic object you can use to paint anything, from images to text.

Of course, once you go custom, you are responsible for drawing everything (unfortunately).  See [VisualStyles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.visualstyles.visualstyleelement.treeview.item.aspx) in regards to getting the proper TreeView glyphs.

Simple illustration:

```
Private Sub TreeView1_DrawNode(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DrawTreeNodeEventArgs) Handles TreeView1.DrawNode
  Dim nodeLeft As Integer = (e.Node.Level * 16) + 16
  e.Graphics.DrawImage(ImageOne, nodeLeft, e.Bounds.Top)
  e.Graphics.DrawImage(ImageTwo, nodeLeft + 16, e.Bounds.Top)
  e.Graphics.DrawString(e.Node.Text, Me.Font, Brushes.Black, nodeLeft + 32, e.Bounds.Top)
End Sub
```

This example is missing code to draw the tree controls and the selection state, but it shows two images and the node text.  Custom drawing TreeViews are a lot of work.

Comment: Thanks for your response. The link you gave last night was very useful. I've handled drawing child nodes with state images. For all other nodes i set e.DrawDefault = True. This solved my problem and reduced the amount of code i had to write. The only issue remaining is drawing the highlight for the selected child nodes with a state image. i used FillRectangle with SystemBrushes.Highlight but i am not having a consistent look. I will look at the VisualStyles link you provided in your update for any inspiration.